# How to open/stream .zip files through Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have zip files that I would like to open 'through' Spark. I can open .gzip file no problem because of Hadoops native Codec support, but am unable to do so with .zip files.

Is there an easy way to read a zip file in your Spark code? I've also searched for zip codec implementations to add to the CompressionCodecFactory, but am unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There was no solution with python code and I recently had to read zips in pyspark. And, while searching how to do that I came across this question. So, hopefully this'll help others.

```
import zipfile
import io

def zip_extract(x):
    in_memory_data = io.BytesIO(x[1])
    file_obj = zipfile.ZipFile(in_memory_data, "r")
    files = [i for i in file_obj.namelist()]
    return dict(zip(files, [file_obj.open(file).read() for file in files]))


zips = sc.binaryFiles("hdfs:/Testing/*.zip")
files_data = zips.map(zip_extract).collect()
```

In the above code I returned a dictionary with filename in the zip as a key and the text data in each file as the value. you can change it however you want to suit your purposes.

Comment: This worked fine for my not-so-large zip files. Other fun part is that once you have the binary of the unpacked zip file, there's no easy way to get it to hdfs or s3. What I had to do was to write it to a local file using python and then take it from there and move it to s3.

Comment: Is there a way I can apply same logic for `bz2` files. I am trying to not able to convert rdd to `BytesIO`

Comment: @GaurangShah, there is. You can use `bz2.decompress` to decompress bz2 in memory. For example `decompressed_x = bz2.decompress(x[1])`.

Comment: does this work for `.gz` files too? Also Im not able to display it as a dataframe even after converting to a dataframe , as i have a text file

Answer (score 6):

@user3591785 pointed me in the correct direction, so I marked his answer as correct.

For a bit more detail, I was able to search for ZipFileInputFormat Hadoop, and came across this link: http://cotdp.com/2012/07/hadoop-processing-zip-files-in-mapreduce/

Taking the ZipFileInputFormat and its helper ZipfileRecordReader class, I was able to get Spark to perfectly open and read the zip file.

```
    rdd1  = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("/Users/myname/data/compressed/target_file.ZIP", ZipFileInputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class, new Job().getConfiguration());
```

The result was a map with one element. The file name as key, and the content as the value, so I needed to transform this into a JavaPairRdd. I'm sure you could probably replace Text with BytesWritable if you want, and replace the ArrayList with something else, but my goal was to first get something running.

```
JavaPairRDD<String, String> rdd2 = rdd1.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Text, Text>, String, String>() {

    @Override
    public Iterable<Tuple2<String, String>> call(Tuple2<Text, Text> textTextTuple2) throws Exception {
        List<Tuple2<String,String>> newList = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, String>>();

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(textTextTuple2._2.getBytes());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        Tuple2 newTuple = new Tuple2(line.split("\\t")[0],line);
            newList.add(newTuple);
        }
        return newList;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Please try the code below:

```
using API sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    hadoopConf,
    InputFormat.class,
    ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class)
```

Comment: Thank you, but would it be possible to give a sample use case?

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue and I've solved with the following code

```
sparkContext.binaryFiles("/pathToZipFiles/*")
.flatMap { case (zipFilePath, zipContent) =>

        val zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(zipContent.open())

        Stream.continually(zipInputStream.getNextEntry)
        .takeWhile(_ != null)
        .flatMap { zipEntry => ??? }
    }
```

Comment: If there is multiple file in a zip file, I am able to read only first file. Can you please provide code snippet for unzipping multiple file. I also have referred https://github.com/eric-maynard/spark-ETL/blob/master/scala/Example%201.scala link

Comment: @VaijnathPolsane please check my answer

Answer (score 4):

**This answer only collects the previous knowledge and I share my experience.**

## ZipFileInputFormat

I tried following [@Tinku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581125/1549135) and [@JeffLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28636651/1549135) answers, and use imported `ZipFileInputFormat` together with `sc.newAPIHadoopFile` API. **But this did not work for me.** And I do not know how would I put [com-cotdp-hadoop](https://github.com/cotdp/com-cotdp-hadoop) lib on my production cluster. I am not responsible for the setup.

## ZipInputStream

[@Tiago Palma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364913/1549135) gave a good advice, but he did not finish his answer and I struggled quite some time to actually get the decompressed output.

By the time I was able to do so, I had to prepare all the theoretical aspects, which you can find in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45958182/1549135

But the missing part of the mentioned answer is reading the `ZipEntry`:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;   

sc.binaryFiles(path, minPartitions)
      .flatMap { case (name: String, content: PortableDataStream) =>
        val zis = new ZipInputStream(content.open)
        Stream.continually(zis.getNextEntry)
              .takeWhile(_ != null)
              .flatMap { _ =>
                  val br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis))
                  Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
              }}
```

Comment: Can it extract large files. Which are like 10 to 12gigs Zip File. I am getting memory exception

Comment: can we do it for 7z files

Answer (score 2):

```
using API sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(hadoopConf, InputFormat.class, ImmutableBytesWritable.class, Result.class)
```

File name should be pass using conf

```
conf=( new Job().getConfiguration())
conf.set(PROPERTY_NAME from your input formatter,"Zip file address")
sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, ZipFileInputFormat.class, Text.class, Text.class)
```

Please Find  `PROPERTY_NAME` from your input formatter for set path

Comment: Using above code, I was able execute it successfully till 56MB,  but it is getting fail for the file with size 338MB, I am end up with exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
 at hydrograph.engine.spark.zipread.ZipFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ZipFileRecordReader.java:105).......

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.read.text("yourGzFile.gz")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.