# How can i make dataset/dataframe from compressed(.zip) local file in apache spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, zip

I have large compressed(.zip) files around 10 GB each. I need to read content of file inside zip without unzipping it and want to apply transformations.

```
   System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", user)

   println("Creating SparkConf")
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DFS Read Write Test")

   println("Creating SparkContext")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   var textFile = sc.textFile(filePath)

   println("Count...."+textFile.count())

   var df = textFile.map(some code)
```

`
When i passing a any .txt,.log,.md etc.. above is working fine. But when pass .zip files the it giving Zero Count.

1. Why it is giving count Zero
2. Please suggest me correct way of doing this, If am totally wrong.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark/)

Comment: I went through that link already. But i am seeking reason why count being zero. reason for that also.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong as I just tried with a zip and a bzip2 file and the counts just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform this task like this, it's a different operation then simply loading other kind of files which spark supports.

```
val rdd  = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("file.zip", ZipFileInputFormat.class,Text.class, Text.class, new Job().getConfiguration());
```