# Why are my `binaryFiles` empty when I collect them in pyspark?

Tags: python, hadoop, zip, pyspark, binaryfiles

I have two zip files on hdfs in the same folder : `/user/path-to-folder-with-zips/`.

I pass that to "binaryfiles" in pyspark:

```
zips = sc.binaryFiles('/user/path-to-folder-with-zips/')
```

I'm trying to unzip the zip files and do things to the text files in them, so I tried to just see what the content will be when I try to deal with the RDD.  I did it like this:

```
zips_collected = zips.collect()
```

But, when I do that, it gives an empty list:

```
>> zips_collected
[]
```

I know that the zips are not empty - they have textfiles.  The documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html) says

*Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.*

What am I doing wrong here?  I know I can't view the contents of the file because it is zipped and therefore binary.  But, I should at least be able to see *SOMETHING*.  Why does it not return anything?

There can be more than one file per zip file, but the contents are always something like this:

```
rownum|data|data|data|data|data
rownum|data|data|data|data|data
rownum|data|data|data|data|data
```

Comment: It occurred to me that perhaps this is an issue with the *type* of zip file.  How do I find out what type of zip file this is?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that each zip file contains a single text file (code is easily changed for multiple text files). You need to read the contents of the zip file first via `io.BytesIO` before processing line by line. Solution is loosely based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36511190/234233.

```
import io
import gzip

def zip_extract(x):
    """Extract *.gz file in memory for Spark"""
    file_obj = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(x[1]), mode="r")
    return file_obj.read()

zip_data = sc.binaryFiles('/user/path-to-folder-with-zips/*.zip')
results = zip_data.map(zip_extract) \
                  .flatMap(lambda zip_file: zip_file.split("\n")) \
                  .map(lambda line: parse_line(line))
                  .collect()
```

Comment: My code is exactly like that, almost verbatim.  But it throws an error.  That's why I thought I would just run "`collect`", just to see if there even is anything in the RDD.  But it returns empty list?  This is how I started debugging.

Comment: How many text files are in each zip file -- 1 or more? Also, could you post a small sample of zip files? If the data are proprietary, that's fine -- use artificial data instead.

Comment: Sure, it's just a bunch of psv files.  Each files is on the order of 10's of MB

Comment: Also, your example is for `gzip` files.  I'm using zip files