# How to read gz compressed file by pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have line data in .gz compressed format. I have to read it in pyspark
Following is the code snippet

```
rdd = sc.textFile("data/label.gz").map(func)
```

But I could not read the above file successfully. How do I read gz compressed file. I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256631/why-are-my-binaryfiles-empty-when-i-collect-them-in-pyspark) but my current version of spark is different that the version in that question. I expect there should be some built in function as in hadoop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my \`binaryFiles\` empty when I collect them in pyspark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256631/why-are-my-binaryfiles-empty-when-i-collect-them-in-pyspark)

Comment: It's not one to one duplicate, but you have necessary code snippet there :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Spark document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html) clearly specify that you can read `gz` file automatically:

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support
>   running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For
>   example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"),
>   textFile("/my/directory/*.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/*.gz").

I'd suggest running the following command, and see the result:

```
rdd = sc.textFile("data/label.gz")

print rdd.take(10)
```

Assuming that spark finds the the file `data/label.gz`, it will print the 10 rows from the file.

Note, that the default location for a file like `data/label.gz` will be in the hdfs folder of the spark-user. Is it there?

Answer (score 8):

You can load compressed files directly into dataframes through the spark instance, you just need to specify the compression in the path:

```
df = spark.read.csv("filepath/part-000.csv.gz")
```

You can also optionally specify if a header present or if schema needs applying too

```
df = spark.read.csv("filepath/part-000.csv.gz", header=True, schema=schema).
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write the error message you got, but it's probably not going well for you because [gzipped files are not splittable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492967/dealing-with-a-large-gzipped-file-in-spark). You need to use a splittable compression codec, like bzip2.

Comment: if you run `sc.textFile("data/label.gz").count()` it shows 0?