# (PY)Spark: How to read a ".txt" file with extension name ".gz"

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to load a pure txt RDD in spark. But for some reasons, the filename of the file to be loaded must be named as "xxx.gz". This file, by default, is recognized as a gz file when using sc.textFile. How can I tell spark to recognize the file as a pure txt file?

Comment: That's not a text file. `gz` is the extension for [GZip packages](https://www.gzip.org/). That GZip package may contain one or more text files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read from a gzip file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902540/read-from-a-gzip-file-in-python)

Comment: This is a spark problem, which is mentioned in the tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read gz compressed file by pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761912/how-to-read-gz-compressed-file-by-pyspark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html).

```
gzip.open(filename, mode='rb', compresslevel=9, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)
```