# Fail to read .zip file in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, databricks

I am able to read .gz files through spark  csv and getting expected result. But while trying to read .zip file spark is giving unexpected results like wV�J�.f�T   n .

I have visited "**https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress**", but didn't find any compression codec for .zip file.

I searched on stackoverflow but didn't get any satisfactory result for that.

Please provide more information if anyone has faced same issue or have any solution on that.

Comment: Did you tried to check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please post your code, so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: But my requirement is to read .zip file like we read csv files. Ex sparkSession.read.option("","").schema("userdefinedschema").format("").load("abc.zip")