# spark read contents of zip file in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit, spark-shell

I Am trying to read data from zip file

can read whole text file as below

```
val f = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://")
```

but don`t know, how to read text data inside zip file

Is there any possible way to do it, if yes please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open/stream .zip files through Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark)

Comment: I have seen that, but it was not clearly explained

Comment: if it is a gzip file  it will be simple  val rdd= sc.textFile("path")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an RDD from the zipFile with the newAPIHadoopFile command.

```
import com.cotdp.hadoop.ZipFileInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job

val zipFileRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
        "hdfs://tmp/sample_zip/LoanStats3a.csv.zip",
        classOf[ZipFileInputFormat],
        classOf[Text],
        classOf[BytesWritable],
        new Job().getConfiguration())
println("The file contents are: " + zipFileRDD.map(s => new String(s._2.getBytes())).first())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I was exactly looking into