# How do i read a delimited file inside a zip file in spark rdd

Tags: apache-spark

I have a HDFS location and there is a zip file inside that location

HDFS location /development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/records.zip

```
 scala> val loc = "/development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/"
 loc: String = "/development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/"

 scala> val rdd = sc.textFile(loc)
 rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /development/staging/b8baf3f4-abce-11eb-8592-0242ac110032/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:26

  scala> rdd.take(2)
  res0: Array[String] = Array(PK????????]Rďż˝Rďż˝ďż˝*ďż˝????ďż˝??? ???2972120.datďż˝Sďż˝rďż˝0? 
   ďż˝ďż˝*ďż˝0ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝?t?ďż˝]Tďż˝Đ–??ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝
 `ďż˝6Ř·ďż˝kU;Pďż˝Mďż˝ďż˝ rSOďż˝;Gďż˝ďż˝pďż˝ďż˝?ďż˝ďż˝?ďż˝Z1^3@ďż˝^ďż˝ďż˝ ďż˝ďż˝Fďż˝ďż˝Ů•bďż˝?~,Ů– 
 ďż˝u6ďż˝Dďż˝ďż˝'ďż˝@ďż˝??ďż˝ďż˝L*ďż˝Gp?ďż˝kcLďż˝7!rďż˝p1ďż˝1eďż˝ďż˝ a*.{? 
   ďż˝.;ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝sďż˝(ďż˝)ďż˝, ?ďż˝=ďż˝9U<"*!?5ďż˝ďż˝?;ďż˝?ďż˝?ďż˝Ů…d{h} 
  ďż˝ďż˝gGďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ďż˝ ďż˝?ďż˝Z)
```

but it produces output differently

Can you help on how do i read a file inside a zip file using spark RDD  There is only one file inside my zip file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open/stream .zip files through Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569788/how-to-open-stream-zip-files-through-spark)

Comment: Looking for a solution in scala code

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
import java.io.{ IOException, FileOutputStream, FileInputStream, File }
import java.util.zip.{ ZipEntry, ZipInputStream }
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

//Unzip the file and copy the internal contents outside in new location
object Unzip extends App {

  val INPUT_ZIP_FILE: String = "src/resources/my-zip.zip";
val OUTPUT_FOLDER: String = "src/resources/my-zip";

def unZipIt(zipFile: String, outputFolder: String): Unit = {

  val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)

  try {

    //output directory
    val folder = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER);
    if (!folder.exists()) {
      folder.mkdir();
    }

    //zip file content
    val zis: ZipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));
    //get the zipped file list entry
    var ze: ZipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();

    while (ze != null) {

      val fileName = ze.getName();
      val newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

      System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

      //create folders
      new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

      val fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

      var len: Int = zis.read(buffer);

      while (len > 0) {

        fos.write(buffer, 0, len)
        len = zis.read(buffer)
      }

      fos.close()
      ze = zis.getNextEntry()
    }

    zis.closeEntry()
    zis.close()

  } catch {
    case e: IOException => println("exception caught: " + e.getMessage)
  }

}

Unzip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE, OUTPUT_FOLDER)
val sac = new SparkContext("local[*]", " first Program");
val sqlc = new SQLContext(sac);
val rdd = sac.textFile("src/resources/my-zip/sample.txt")
rdd.take(1).foreach(println)
/*val rddFromFile = sqlc.sparkContext.textFile("src/resources/my-zip/sample.txt")
println(rddFromFile.getClass)

println("##Get data Using collect")
rddFromFile.collect().foreach(f=>{
  println(f)
})*/

}
```

Not sure if this achieves what you want to do, but may be could help a bit!